# Перебор нескольких массивов

Tags: java, массивы

Имеется 3 строковых массива разной длины.
Как перебрать все 3 массива через 1 цикл?

Comment: делайте цикл for, где количество проходов будет равно длине самого большого массива......берете элементы и параллельно смотрите если итерация больше чем длина других двух коротких, то их пропускаете....

Answer (score 2):

```
        String[] a = new String[10];
        String[] b = new String[20];
        String[] c = new String[30];

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(a.length, Math.max(b.length, c.length)); i++) {
            if(i < a.length) {
                // операция массивом a
            }
            if(i < b.length) {
                // операция массивом b
            }
            if(i < c.length) {
            // операция массивом c
            }
        }
```

Comment: вместо `max` можно просто написать `i < a.length || i < b.length || i < c.length`, скорее всего будет работать быстрее. ну либо вычислить максимум один раз до цикла, а не считать на каждой итерации.

Comment: @AlexChermenin кто знает какие операции с массивами будут производиться в теле цикла? Например при выполнении определенного условия может выполняться следующий код: `a = new String(a.length*2);` Конечно, если такое исключено, то лучше максимальное значение вычислить до цикла или сделать как написали вы.

Answer (score 1):

```
String arr1 = new String[]{"a"};
String arr2 = new String[]{"a", "b"};
String arr3 = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};

for(int i = 0; i < arr1.length + arr2.length + arr3.length; i++) {
    String arr;
    int indexOfArr;
    if(i < arr1.length) { 
        arr = arr1; 
        indexOfArr = i; 
    } else if (i < arr1.length + arr2.length) { 
        arr = arr2; 
        indexOfArr = i - arr1.length; 
    } else { 
        arr = arr3; 
        indexOfArr = i - arr1.length - arr2.length; 
    }
    System.out.println(arr[indexOfArr]);
}
```

Comment: какие-то сложные замуты)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, просто это первое что в голову пришло) Вроде, должно работать и относительно гибкое оно - индекс массива известен)

Comment: @Roman, я не буду возражать против правок)